# Workbox registerRoute issue with cashing

Tags: workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

This is my compiled service-worker with workbox-webpack-plugin (InjectManifest):

```
importScripts("/dist/precache-manifest.fec4937a7fe6a37db29b13fc00b6d92a.js", "/dist/workbox-v3.2.0/workbox-sw.js");
workbox.setConfig({modulePathPrefix: "/dist/workbox-v3.2.0"});
importScripts('/idb.js');
importScripts('/utility.js');

var STATIC_FILES = [
    '/index.html',
    '/idb.js',
    '/utility.js',
];

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    'http://54.xx.xxx.57/(.*)',
    workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
        cacheName: 'cache-posts'
    }),
    'GET'
);

self.__precacheManifest = STATIC_FILES.concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.suppressWarnings();
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});
```

Precaching is ok, but I can't figure out how to make registerRoute to work and I tried several things. SW just doesn't cash anything coming from 'http://54.xx.xxx.57/'. Please, help... :)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it is not regular expression in registerRoute.
Should be:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('http://54.xx.xxx.57/(.*)'),
  workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
    cacheName: 'cache-posts'
  }),
 'GET');
```

Comment: That was one of the thing I tried and it didn't worked... also like many others. Really strange :/

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression has errors in it.
You should escape the forward slash like this.

```
 '/http:\/\/54.xx.xxx.57\/(.*)/'
```

Ideally the dots should be also escaped if you don't want to catch any character instead of them like so:

```
'/http:\/\/54\.xx\.xxx\.57\/(.*)/'
```